# use echo .??* and show all hidden files, but not . or .. themselves

Tags: unix, filter, sh, glob

Hi I'm learning unix and I want to run a `echo .??*` that show all of my files starting with `.` but does not show `.` or `..`.

I mean the command runs fine but doesn't show `.a` `.b` `.c` files.

If the files are

```
. .. .a .b .c .aa .bb .cc .aaa .abc a b c aaa bbb ccc
```

the output of the echo must be

```
.a .b .c .aa .bb .cc .aaa .abc
```

How can I complete the command?

Comment: Does `echo .*` do what you want?

Comment: @Blorgbeard No.

Comment: no, echo .* shows . ..

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: Ok, zsh (or zsh with my config) doesn't show `.` and `..` for `echo .*`. Bash does though.

Comment: Look here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1168/how-to-glob-every-hidden-file-except-current-and-parent-directory

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the shell you're using, but in bash you can do the following (assuming `extglob` is enabled: `shopt -s extglob`):

```
echo .@(.?|[!.])*
```

`@(...|...)` is an "or" pattern. This matches every file that matches either `..?*` or `.[!.]*`.

`..?*` matches files that start with `..`, followed by at least one other character. This finds all names that start with `..` except for `..` itself.

`.[!.]*` matches files that start with `.`, followed by a non-`.` character. This matches all "normal" hidden files (whose second character is not a dot).

Note that in your example none of the files start with `..`, so `.[!.]*` would be sufficient to produce the desired output.